# Simple and elegant way to override local file If exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Looking for elegant and simple solution to have "local configuration override" files.

The idea is to be able to have local configuration that will not ask to be added to git repository every time.

For that I need to include local.config.js **if it exists**.

I have global app configuration in `config.js` with configuration like

```js
export const config = {
  API_URL="https://some.host",
}
```

and `config.local.js`

```js
export const config = {
  API_URL="https://other.address",
}
```

there's `.gitignore`:

```
config.local.js
```

Difficulty:
**I do not want to add a node module to project just for this one thing.** I believe there should be an elegant way to do this in one or few lines, but have not found any so far.

Things that I tried:

**1.**

```
try {
  const {
    apiUrl: API_URL,
  } = require('./config.local.js');
  config. API_URL =apiUrl;
} catch (e) {

}
```

`require` does not work inside try{} block.

**2.**

```js
const requireCustomFile = require.context('./', false, /config.local.js$/);

requireCustomFile.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  requireCustomFile(fileName);
});
```

does not work.

**3.**

```js
export const config = require('./config.local.js') || {default:'config = {...}'}
```

does not work.

**4.**

Using .env and settings environment variable: I need to override whole array of configuration values. Not one by one.

Comment: How do you start your node app locally? With `npm start` (and a corresponding `package.json`) or directly in the command prompt? Either way you may consider adding an environment variable which can then be accessed and switched on via `process.argv`. More here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv - let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: Yes, I looked into that too. I need to avoid .env var because I need to override whole array of configuration values.

Comment: This does not use `.env` per your request in the post. It uses `process.argv`, a native function of node which requires no additional modules and will allow you to accomplish your goal in 1 line of code if you use a ternary expression.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `process.argv`. It is native to node as [documented here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) and does not use .env

It inspects the command values used to start the app. Since these should be different between your local and production environments, it's an easy way to switch with no additional modules required.

**command prompt to start your node app:**
(this might also be in `package.json` and incurred via `npm start` if you're using that approach.)

```sh
$ node index.js local
```

**index.js of your node app:**

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config');

if (process.argv[2] === 'local') {
  // the 3rd argument provided at startup (2nd index) was 'local', so here we are!
  config = require('./config_local');
}

var app = express();

// rest of owl…
```